# Join and aggregating two internal tables into one

Tags: abap

I need to aggregate the below two tables into one, per True_Origin and True_Destination level.

Table 2 (`IT_DATES_OD`):

```
FDate2    Flight_Number2  Origin2  Destination2  Amount3  Amount4
20190501  123             DXB      LOS           5        12
20190501  123             DXB      LOS           22       558
20190501  123             DXB      LOS           2556     4585
```

Table 1 (`IT_TOD_OD`):

```
Flight_Date_OD  Flight_Number_OD  Origin  Destination  True_origin  True_destination  Net_Net_Net  Amount2
20190501        123               DXB     LOS          DXB          NBO               5            12
20190501        123               DXB     LOS          DXB          ADD               22           558
20190501        123               DXB     LOS          DXB          LOL               2556         4585
```

I can aggregate using common fields (Date, Flight Number, Origin, Destination) but I can't aggregate on a detailed level on True_origin and True_destination.

```
SORT IT_DATES_TOD BY FDATE2 FLIGHT_NUMBER2 ORIGIN2 DESTINATION2 ASCENDING.

CLEAR WA_OUTPUT.

LOOP AT IT_DATES_TOD INTO WA_DATES_TOD WHERE FDATE2 <> ''.
      WA_OUTPUT-FDATE         = WA_DATES_TOD-FDATE2.
      WA_OUTPUT-FLIGHT_NUMBER = WA_DATES_TOD-FLIGHT_NUMBER2.
      WA_OUTPUT-ORIGIN        = WA_DATES_TOD-ORIGIN2.
      WA_OUTPUT-DESTINATION   = WA_DATES_TOD-DESTINATION2.

   LOOP AT IT_TOD_OD INTO WA_TOD_OD 
       WHERE FLIGHT_DATE_OD   = WA_DATES_TOD-FDATE2
         AND FLIGHT_NUMBER_OD = WA_DATES_TOD-FLIGHT_NUMBER2
         AND ORIGIN           = WA_DATES_TOD-ORIGIN2
         AND DESTINATION      = WA_DATES_TOD-DESTINATION2.

      WA_OUTPUT-TRUE_ORIGIN      = WA_TOD_OD-TRUE_ORIGIN.
      WA_OUTPUT-TRUE_DESTINATION = WA_TOD_OD-TRUE_DESTINATION.
      WA_OUTPUT-NET_NET_NET      = WA_TOD_OD-NET_NET_NET.
      WA_OUTPUT-RE_PRO_REVFUEL   = 0.
      WA_OUTPUT-BLOCK_HOUR       = 0.

      APPEND WA_OUTPUT TO IT_OUTPUT.
   ENDLOOP.
ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: I had to edit thoroughly the question because it was really unclear. Could you please verify that I didn't introduce errors, and please show the **expected result** for the tables you mention? Please conform the formatting rules of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -1):

Please have a look at the collect Syntax in ABAP:
COLLECT statement in ABAP is used for inserting the components of a work area into an internal table by avoiding duplicate entries and also in a summarized way.
Syntax

```
COLLECT <line> INTO <itab>
```

When you use collect statement the following steps are occurring.

First it will check in internal table for any record matching with the key in work area data.

- If it couldn’t find any matching record, then the new data from work area will be inserted in internal table
- If any record found with the same key, then instead of inserting a new record, it will add the numeric field values of work area components with the corresponding field components in the matched record and update the internal table record.

both of your itabs should use the Destination structure:

```
Date      F_Number Orign  Destin T_origin T_destin Amount Amount2
```

so the collect command can make use add functionality of the numeric fields.